# Rectangular array with holes

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a rectangular grid with numbers in some cells (but not all of them), in a way such that it's easy to select a given row or column.

What I did so far is to create the list of the positions of the numbers in the grid and the list of the numbers contained in the grid, so that I can select the number at position (i,j) with `numbers[positions.index([i,j])`, but this is not very handy, especially if I need, for example, to find the minimum of the values in a given column.

Is there a way to create the grid so that, for example, I can select elements with `grid[i][j]` and columns with `grid[:][j]` or something similar? The programming language is Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) for this. It lets you create an array, which can index a single value with `array[i,j]` or a full column with `array[:,j]`.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by holes, but numpy will require you to have a value in every spot in the array. The best thing I believe you can set it to a preset "empty" value.

Comment: Thanks, numpy's array seems useful, but using a preset empty value (e.g. `None`) is annoying, as I can't just use `min(grid[:,j])` for example. I guess there is no way to pick an empty value that is automatically filtered out, in some sense?

Comment: Using `numpy.amax` or `numpy.amin` you can pass to only check for values where a condition is met. For example, instead of `min(grid[:,j])`, you can use `numpy.amin(grid[:,j], initial=0, where=(a != val))` which would exclude every value that's equal to `val`. The initial is just the default if no number is found that both passes the where and is greater/less than its value. Unfortunately you have to set it if you're passing a where, but you can set it to `numpy.inf` or `-numpy.inf` to make it only return if no value gets past the where.

Answer (score 0):

Store your grid as a 2D array (a matrix) and use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```py
first_column = [row[0] for row in grid]
second_column = [row[1] for row in grid]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to have a large proportion of the "cells" that are unused, you could try using a dictionary with the coordinates as key in a tuple.

```
matrix = dict()

matrix[1,3] = 13
matrix[1,5] = 15
matrix[2,3] = 23
matrix[2,7] = 27
matrix[3,7] = 37

valuesInRow2 = [v for (r,c),v in matrix.items() if r==2]
# [23,27]
```

By creating a subclass of dict to manage indexing and overriding operators, you could get it to behave exactly the way you want:

```
class Sparse(dict):

    def __init__(self,rows=0,cols=0):
        super().__init__()
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols

    def __indexToRanges(self,rowIndex,colIndex):
        scalar = isinstance(rowIndex,int) and isinstance(colIndex,int)
        if isinstance(rowIndex,slice):
            rowRange = range(*rowIndex.indices(self.rows))
        else:
            rowRange = range(rowIndex,rowIndex+1)
        if isinstance(colIndex,slice):
            colRange = range(*colIndex.indices(self.cols))
        else:
            colRange = range(colIndex,colIndex+1)
        return rowRange,colRange,scalar

    def __getitem__(self,indexes):
        row,col = indexes
        rowRange,colRange,scalar = self.__indexToRanges(row,col)
        if scalar: return super()._getitem((row,col))
        return [v for (r,c),v in self.items() if r in rowRange and c in colRange]

    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        row,col=index
        rowRange,colRange,scalar = self.__indexToRanges(row,col)
        if scalar:
            self.rows = max(self.rows,row+1)
            self.cols = max(self.cols,col+1)
            return super().__setitem__((row,col),value)
```

usage:

```
matrix = Sparse()

matrix[1,3] = 13
matrix[1,5] = 15
matrix[2,3] = 23
matrix[2,7] = 27
matrix[3,7] = 37

print("sum of column 3:",     sum(matrix[:,3]) )  # 36
print("sum of row 2:",        sum(matrix[2,:]) )  # 50
print("top left 4x4 values:", matrix[:4,:4]    )  # [13, 23]
```